# Please help me about query database

Tags: sql

This is my tables

Room

```
Room_no 

0001
```

Tenant

```
ALICA 0001(Room_no  )         
Alex  0001(Room_no)
```

2 tenants can live 1 room.

This is a result that I want form query

```
0001 ALICA Alex
```

How can I do this in sql select command.

PS. sorry for the tables that I show you I don't know how to post table in stackoverflow.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Comment: What database are you using? What have you tried so far that isn't working for you?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to tell you guys it's MySql.

Comment: use output from mysql `DESC Room` command to describe your table schema where `Room` is your table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` function  with `SEPARATOR` space

This query will help you if you need information from both the table.

```
SELECT 
      Room.Room_no, GROUP_CONCAT(Tenant_name SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM 
      Room 
JOIN 
      Tenant ON Room.Room_no = Tanent.Room_no
GROUP BY 
      Room.Room_no
```

As per your question you only need to get the info from one table (`Tenant`). so now use the below query

```
SELECT 
      Room_no, GROUP_CONCAT(Tenant_name SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM 
      Tenant 
GROUP BY 
      Room_no
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this help

edit field name match your table

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tenant SEPARATOR ',') FROM room GROUP BY room_no
```